# even and odd function and the interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So sin is odd and cos is even function.

If $cos(x)$ is $0 \ge x \ge \pi $ is cos still even ?

And if $sin(x)$ is $0 \ge x \ge \pi $ is sin still odd ?

Because when we integrate   $ \int_0^\pi sin (x) dx = 2 \neq 0$

When odd function, $sin(x)$ in this case should be zero, when integrated.

Thank you.

Comment: Note, for functions with a domain of the real numbers, the definition of an even function is that $f(-x) = f(x)$ and an odd function is that $f(-x) = -f(x)$, for all real $x$. Since the integration goes from $0$ to $\pi$, whether $\sin(x)$ is even or odd doesn't have any direct effect on the result.

Comment: So if I had to work on fourier series on $0\le x \le \pi$, and $f(x)$ is an odd function. Fourier would be of the form $f(x)={a_0\over2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \sin(kx)$

Comment: Note any linear combination of odd functions still forms an odd function. As such, using what you wrote, consider $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + g(x)$ where $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k \sin(kx)$. In this case, $f(-x) = -f(x) = -\frac{a_0}{2} - g(x) = -\frac{a_0}{2} + g(-x)$, but also $f(-x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + g(-x)$. Equating these $2$ expressions gives that $a_0 = 0$. Thus, you can simplify your expression but, otherwise, I believe it's correct. Also, more simply, note that for odd functions that $f(0) = -f(0)$, so $f(0) = 0$. Thus, $\sin(0) = 0$ and you can more directly get that $a_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is  no such thing as even and odd functions on $[0,\pi]$. The concept makes sense only for intervals symmetric about $0$. Besides, $0 \geq x \geq \pi$ makes no sense since $\pi$ is positive.

Comment: But clearly from the question the OP did not mean $\pi$ to be the usual $3.14159\ldots$ constant, but some arbitrary negative number.

Comment: @MarkFischler He writes $\int_0^{\pi} \sin\, x dx=2$. Is this true for any negative number $\pi$?.

Comment: I assume you meant to write "There is *no* such thing as even or odd functions on $[0, \pi]$."

Comment: @N.F.Taussig What a silly typo that was! Thanks for the comment.